# Account for Chrome users who set their fonts to large or x-large

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, xhtml

Ok, so I have a client complaining about how a user who set their fonts too large in Chrome causes the site to render badly--which it does. My natural reaction was to tell them that we could either shrink the font for them or they could just tell people to use normal fonts for their browser. I know that it is a good practice to try and make designs that accommodate as many browsers as possible, but there has to be a limit. People do some crazy s%^&. It seems to me that you have to tell people to just deal with it after a while or you will never be able to actually do anything that actually looks good for 99% of users. Anyways, does anyone know of a work around? I will also take opinions on a good response for the client.

**Update**

Ok, so figuring I set the page to use em instead of px. What about ASPX controls that you can only specify an integer value for the height and width? I assume this integer value would be set to pixels.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site?

Comment: yes http://lionfront.com/Anzalone. The page in question is the Team Page under the "Who We Are" Sub Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your client is well within his rights to point this out. Generally the reason people will set browser font sizes above the "normal" threshold is because of poor eyesight. For that reason it is not only good practice but a mark of decency to accommodate people who are not fortunate enough to have 20/20 vision.

The solution to the problem is using `em` sizes and `min-widths`. while this will not produce pixel perfect layouts, it will produce perfect relative layouts. All layouts will have exactly the same proportions no matter how large the or small the font-size.

It turns out that calculating sizes of things like buttons is also much easier when using `em`'s.

Here's how you do it.

```
body {
    // Allow the font size to be as big as the browser wants.
    font-size: 100%;
}

.main-container {
    // allow you body container to stretch as big as it needs
    // You could also specify this in em's
    min-width: 960px;
}

.button {
    // want some bigger text, that's fine
    font-size: 1.2em;
    // the rest of button is now normalised so 1em is actually 1.2em

    // set the width by counting the characters in the button text
    // remember to take any padding on the button into account
    // in the width
    width: 10em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

It's pretty easy to get close to pixel perfect using `em`'s just try to remember that the normal browser font size is around `16px` so `5px` is roughly 1/3 of 16 
so in `em`'s `0.3em`.

In other words as a guiding hand or general rule to calculate sizes.

```
    0.3em = 5px
```

The thing you have to remember about `em`'s is that they inherit from the parent container.

e.g.

```
.my-content {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.my-content .my-paragraph {
    font-size: 1em; 
    // this is actually 1.2em because it inherits and normalises
    // from it's parent
}

my.content .my-paragraph .my-span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    // is 1.2 + 20% 
}
```

it will keep chaining down like this. So the rule is, only specify font-sizes directly on the the element to be styled not it's parent.

The great thing about your site now is that it will look perfectly formed at any size. Which will be great on the plethora of mobile devices, tablets, high-res monitors, 50inch flat screens or 50ft informational display's.

And you helped all the people who have poor eyesight view your site and your hard work in all it's relative beauty.

Comment: I would love to help you there but I have no experience of ASPX controls. My guess would be that they must support em's somehow. Do they set the widths on the elements `width=""` attribute? or compile a stylesheet? If they apply the dimensions on the attribute you could add a class to the control. Provide a `width` of `0` to the ASPX controls and then set it in CSS yourself... other than stab in the dark I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution is to  use `em` widths (for example 400em) instead of pixel widths (for example `width: 960px`). This bases the widths of your elements on the font size, rather than a strict pixel value.

However, in order to achieve this you must do it from the start of a project. Also, pages will not be the pixel-perfect masterpieces that your designer handed you in Photoshop.

**Re: Update**

I'm not entirely sure, but if at all possible, specify a `CssClass` attribute rather than a `width` attribute, and then reference that in your CSS to use `em`s in stead of pixels.

Comment: Well we wrote a CMS for this site. The end user uploads much of the actual html, good luck making them use em instead of px. Anyhow, this is actually a good idea. Thanks! Then what about small resolution monitors that also had large fonts set? Then I am screwed.

Comment: That is really unfortunate. On the other hand, it sounds like it's the end user's problem, not yours ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about a tasteful button at the bottom of the main window that says, "Use site designed for larger fonts.," and when a user clicks on it it simply feeds a different CSS file to their computer, with appropriately sized fonts?  I think you should be able to make it as transparent to your site coding as possible, within limits.  I would look at a CSS fix to the issue (maybe have the particular user send you his/her settings to test with) and then fix and forget.

Comment: While this is a really common sense solution, the end product is that the end user doesn't end up getting any bigger fonts, I would just send them a CSS file that shrinks everything. I don't understand why they don't just ctrl+mouseScroll. Then, everything gets big.

Comment: @Jonathan Henson -- I hear you.  You make a good point about asking the user to take that simple action, but if it is pretty easy to do on your end (for the fonts at least; the graphics might get tricky), you've made the customer happy.  Alternately, you could have a little label that says, "Fonts too large?  Hold down the Control key and scroll your mouse to adjust."